# How to get Node.js to return an array of objects separated from rest of data

Tags: node.js, logic

I cant seem to logic this one out. I am calling a database and getting response 'resp' which is an array of key value pairs.
Response is what I am returning from the function I have below.
Most of the data I just wish to return as an array of objects containing two key value pairs (Type/data), and that is achieved elsewhere in the code. **However, if the value of Type is count or counted, I wish to group these in its own array**

```
if (resp[i].Type === "count" || resp[i].Type === "counted" && Response[i-1].Type != "grouping" ) {
     ItemGroup.push({
         Type: resp[i].Type,
         data : resp[i].data})
                       
     var grouping = "grouping"
     Response.push({ Type: grouping,
         data : ItemGroup
     }
}
```

what I want is shown below, however, my code is displaying this but replicating the whole object out 3 times... I am new to JS, so still figuring this all out

```
    {
        "Type": "grouping",
        "data": [
            {
                "Type": "count",
                "data": "this is the data"
            },
            {
                "Type": "count",
                "data": "more data"
            },
            {
                "Type": "counting",
                "data": "input values"
            }
        ]
    },
```